# Why the tuned number of hidden layers (show 3) is not the same as the units (show 4 units) when tuning an ANN model using KerasTurner?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, keras-tuner

I am currently using the `KerasTuner` to tune my **Artificial Neural Network (ANN)** deep learning model for a **binary classification project (tabular dataset )**.  Below is my function to build the model:

```
def build_model(hp):
    
    # Create a Sequential model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    
    # Input Layer: The now model will take as input arrays of shape (None, 67) 
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape = (X_train.shape[1],)))
    
    # Tune number of hidden layers and number of neurons 
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', min_value = 1, max_value = 4)):
        hp_units = hp.Int(f'units_{i}', min_value = 64, max_value = 512, step = 5)
        model.add(Dense(units = hp_units, activation = 'relu'))
    
    # Output Layer
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    # Compile the model
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values = [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = hp_learning_rate), 
                  loss = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
                  metrics = ["accuracy"]
                 )
    
    return model
```

Codes of creating `tuner`:

```
import os

# HyperBand algorithm from keras tuner
hpb_tuner = kt.Hyperband(
    hypermodel = build_model, 
    objective = 'val_accuracy', 
    max_epochs = 500, 
    seed = 42,
    executions_per_trial = 3,
    directory = os.getcwd(),
    project_name = "Medical Claim (ANN)",
)

hpb_tuner.search_space_summary()
```

The best result shows that I have to use **3 hidden layers**. However, why there is a total of **4 hidden layers** shown?
[image]

If I didn't misunderstand, the `num_layers` parameter indicates how many **hidden layers** I have to use in my **ANN**, and parameters `units_0` to `units_3` indicate how many **neurons** I have to use in each hidden layer where `units_0` refers to the first hidden layer, `units_1` refers to the second hidden layer and so forth. The **input layer** of my ANN should **equal the number of features** in my dataset **which is 67** as shown in my code above (within the `build_model` function), so I believe the **units_0** does not refer to the number of neurons in the input layer.

Is there something wrong with my code? Hope any gurus here can solve my doubt and problem!